# Django Haystack: whoosh.index.IndexVersionError: Can't read format -111

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

Setting up django `1.7` with haystack `2.0.0` and whoosh `2.4.0` when I run `python manage.py rebuild_index` get this error:

```
Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()

  ...

  File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whoosh/filedb/filestore.py", line 54, in open_index
    return FileIndex(storage, schema=schema, indexname=indexname)
  File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whoosh/filedb/fileindex.py", line 220, in __init__
    TOC.read(self.storage, self.indexname, schema=self._schema)
  File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whoosh/filedb/fileindex.py", line 113, in read
    raise IndexVersionError("Can't read format %s" % version, version)
whoosh.index.IndexVersionError: Can't read format -111
```

The folder whoosh_index exists.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the index folder ran the index again fixed that error.